# Lubuntu 18.10 LXQt - desktop shortcuts to URL

Tags: lubuntu, shortcuts, 18.10, lxqt

I've just installed Lubuntu 18.10 and struggling to create shortcuts to a URL on the desktop.

In previous versions of Lubuntu I would just drag from the browser's address bar to the desktop but this doesn't seem to work in the new LXQt desktop.

I've tried this in Friefox and Chrome and in both the drag and drop appears to work but the shortcut disappears from the desktop.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are there any icons on your desktop? It may be that you have icons disabled if not.

Comment: It was a fresh install of Lubuntu 18.10 using default options. There weren't any shortcuts placed on the desktop during install but I have added some to applications (dragged from the main menu).

Answer (score 0):

ronmacq, check this out [lubuntu v18.10 LXQt Desktop Applic Icon Change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122323/lubuntu-v18-10-lxqt-desktop-applic-icon-change/1122353#1122353). I don't know exactly how you managed to end up with a reference to said browsers, but it would appear that built v18-10 LXQt Desktop procedure didn't get used. You can have joy however should you left click "Menu --> Internet --> Mouse over and select 'Firefox|Chrome Browser' keeping finger down, dragging over to desktop, raising finger; selecting 'copy here'". The associated metafile will, then get copied to your ~/Desktop, and named [firefox|chrome].desktop. At the moment you have either a soft link or a script in your ~/Desktop that shows up on your desktop, but contians the wrong description data, reference, or code, needed by the desktop manager, to direct it to do the correct action, necessary start the browser. In order to have the browser also open a given page will require more update to given .desktop file, in order to include these directives, as well. And, the same is more true should you want these events to automatically take place on login.